# HTML5 canvas at button click?

Tags: html, canvas

I want to make a menu with options for user to choose before initializing canvas.
How can I do it? I want to make options, user clicks button and page becomes canvas USING the values from previous page (how can I pass them?)

The best thing would be to put sliders to increase/decrease (input type range?) value on the canvas, but can I add a form to a canvas somehow?

Comment: Sure you can 'add a form to a canvas', so long as you're happy to write all of your own gui (& logic) code for the controls that would be drawn on the form. Either that, or use the wheel that has already been created elsewhere. I've seen many libraries for this kind of thing. Bejewelled (the Google Chrome 'app'-game) does exactly this - draws menus and controls on a canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about “Keeping It Simple”

- Create a form that asks all your setup questions.
- Put your canvas directly on top of the form and hide it.
- When the user has answered their questions: hide the form, show the canvas.
- Draw on your canvas.

No need to reinvent any wheels…just HTML.

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/jr4rX/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px; }
    #container{position:relative; width:300px; height:300px;}
    #setup #canvas{
        position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px;
        width:100%; height:100%;
    }
    #setup{padding:10px; border:1px solid blue;}
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    // Hide the canvas while getting user info on form
    $("#canvas").hide();

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    function playGame(circles,rects){

        // hide the completed form and show the canvas
        $("#setup").hide();
        $("#canvas").show();


        // draw user's circles
        ctx.fillStyle="blue";
        for(var n=0;n<circles;n++){
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(n*25+15,25,10,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.restore();
        }

        // draw user's rectangles
        ctx.fillStyle="green";
        for(var n=0;n<rects;n++){
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(n*20+5,75,10,10);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }

    $("#play").click(function(){ 

        var circleCount=$("#circles").val();
        var rectangleCount=$("#rectangles").val();

        playGame( circleCount, rectangleCount ); 

    });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="setup">
            How many Circles<input type="range" id="circles" min="1" max="10"><br>
            How many Rectangles<input type="range" id="rectangles" min="1" max="10"><br>
            <button id="play">Play</button>
        </div>    

        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's very interesting, thanks!
One question, though. Is it a lot harder to make form on the canvas? My project is bouncing balls, and I want to see changes in gravity and speed. While your code is great, it's gonna be a bit cumbersome :)

Or maybe a button on a canvas to go back to the options? (main page) ?

Comment: Yes, creating your own form controls is harder--how much harder varies by coder.  How about placing the range controls for gravity & speed just below the canvas and not hide them at all?  Or place them at the very bottom of the canvas (range controls are very small and tidy).  Alternatively, you could do like Acrobat-PDF and Video Players do...Place the range controls at the bottom of the canvas and make them appear only when the user hovers over them.  I'm *not* trying to push HTML5 controls on you, they're just readily available + debugged + flexible + easy-to-implement + task-specific.

Comment: I'm not that advanced, just staring off the journey :)
It would be good to put the controls on the side/bottom, but my canvas is resizable, 100% of the screen. I will have to sacrifice this feature, won't I ?

Please, chack my project out. Controls do not work yet. Just click play, and then drag-drop to make a path :)

Link: http://www.ii.uj.edu.pl/~kadluczs/MiSK/

Comment: Good news--no sacrificing necessary! You can keep the range controls anchored to the bottom of your canvas *even during resizing*.  In CSS, set your canvas as  position:relative. then set your range controls as position:absolute and bottom:10px.  This results in your anchor controls being pinned to canvas bottom even during resizing.

Comment: Sorry, I garbled that last comment. Wrap the canvas and the range controls in a div element.  Set position:relative in the div and position:absolute in the canvas and range controls.  It's not complex, but too complex for a comment...google "css absolute positioning".